# adding float in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var sssee = "581.30";
var ssser = "1,178.70";


var ssee = sssee.trim().replace(/,/g, "");
var sser = ssser.trim().replace(/,/g, "");
console.log("ee " + ssee)
console.log("er " + sser)
console.log("total " + parseFloat(ssee + sser))
```

In log i see:

> ee 581.30
>
> er 1178.70
>
> total 581.301178

Why is it when adding replace to remove the `,` messes the computation.

Comment: [Oh my...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Variables `ssee` and `sser` are both strings. When you peform `ssee + sser` it would return string `581.301178.70` which would be passed to `parseFloat` function then. When there are two decimal points, only first is taken as correct, that's why `parseFloat` returns `581.301178`.

Check the snippet with correct solution.

```js
var sssee = 581.30;
var ssser = "1178.70";


var ssee = String(sssee).trim().replace(/,/g, "");
var sser = String(ssser).trim().replace(/,/g, "");

console.log("ee " + ssee)
console.log("er " + sser)
console.log("total " + (parseFloat(ssee) + parseFloat(sser)))
```

You should also wrap `ssee` and `ssser` in `String` object before using `trim` and `replace` methods. Without doing that if you provide those variables as floats, instead of strings, your code won't work.

Comment: Also be careful, because if you would make `sssee` float variable not string, then your code would throw an error. Methods `trim` and `replace` are members of `String` prototype.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem:

You concatenate two strings ("581.30" + "1,178.70") to one string ("581.301178.70"). Then you parse it to a float (581.301178).

Solution:

You need to parse each one to a float at first. After do your addition (`parseFloat(ssee) + parseFloat(sser)`).